# Nx + NestJS + TypeORM Database Migrations

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to get database migrations working in my NestJS + TypeORM app that's inside an Nx integrated monorepo workspace. I've tried so many different examples, I can't even list them all. The latest thing I've tried is adding Nx targets for running the migrations. However, I can't quite get things to run correctly.

From what I can tell, I need to be able to do a build step that builds the TypeORM config file, followed by either generating or running the migrations. Here are my targets:

```json
"build-migration-config": {
  "executor": "@nx/js:tsc",
  "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/apps/typeorm-migration",
    "main": "apps/api/src/typeorm.config.ts",
    "tsConfig": "apps/api/tsconfig.app.json"
  }
},
"typeorm-generate-migrations": {
  "executor": "nx:run-commands",
  "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
  "options": {
    "cwd": "apps/api/src/migrations",
    "commands": [
      "npx typeorm -d ../../../../dist/apps/typeorm-migration/src/app/typeorm.config.js migration:generate"
    ],
    "outputPath": "dist/apps/typeorm-migration"
  },
  "dependsOn": ["build-migration-config"]
},
"typeorm-run-migrations": {
  "executor": "nx:run-commands",
  "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
  "options": {
    "cwd": "apps/api/src/migrations",
    "commands": [
      "npx typeorm -d ../../../../dist/apps/typeorm-migration/src/app/typeorm.config.js migration:run"
    ]
  },
  "dependsOn": ["build-migration-config"]
},
```

> The `typeorm-generate-migrations` target and the `typeorm-run-migrations` target almost assuredly won't work yet; I copied that from one of the many examples I read.

I've started to try and get the `build-migration-config` target to run to begin with, and then I'll work my way through the other pieces. However, when I run the task I get an error:

```
> nx run api:build-migration-config

Compiling TypeScript files for project "api"...
apps/api/src/app/app.module.ts:6:40 - error TS6059: File '/Users/user/demos/nx-typeorm-migration-demo/libs/shared/util/models/src/index.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/user/demos/nx-typeorm-migration-demo/apps/api'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

6 import { SharedUtilModelsModule } from '@typeorm-migrations/shared/util/models';
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libs/shared/util/models/src/index.ts:1:15 - error TS6059: File '/Users/user/demos/nx-typeorm-migration-demo/libs/shared/util/models/src/lib/shared-util-models.module.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/user/demos/nx-typeorm-migration-demo/apps/api'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

1 export * from './lib/shared-util-models.module';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libs/shared/util/models/src/lib/shared-util-models.module.ts:3:22 - error TS6059: File '/Users/user/demos/nx-typeorm-migration-demo/libs/shared/util/models/src/lib/post.entity.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/user/demos/nx-typeorm-migration-demo/apps/api'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
  The file is in the program because:
    Imported via './post.entity' from file '/Users/user/demos/nx-typeorm-migration-demo/libs/shared/util/models/src/lib/shared-util-models.module.ts'
    Imported via './lib/post.entity' from file '/Users/user/demos/nx-typeorm-migration-demo/libs/shared/util/models/src/index.ts'
    Root file specified for compilation

3 import { Post } from './post.entity';
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  libs/shared/util/models/src/index.ts:2:15
    2 export * from './lib/post.entity';
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    File is included via import here.
```

The `Post` entity is declared in an Nx lib (which would obviously be standard in a real project) but that apparently isn't the correct way to do this.

My project is in a demo repo, and you can check it out and clone it from GitHub. If you have any experience working on this and can help me out (even if it's a different pattern for generating and running the migrations) I'd be really grateful.

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm stuck too. Did you manage to solve it in the end?